# Bug in 2-D integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Integrate[
 1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r
 , {r, 0, Infinity}
 , {z, -a, a}
 ]
```

> 0

```
Integrate[
 1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r
 , {z, -a, a}
 , {r, 0, Infinity}
 ]
```

> a

Just changing the order of integration limits changes the result. The correct answer is a. Parameter a is otherwise undefined. This is in version Mathematica 10.4.0.0

Comment: There's a question in here, right?

Answer (score 3):

Add the Assumption that `a >  0`

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

Assuming[a > 0, 
 Integrate[1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r,
  {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -a, a}]]

(*  a  *)

Assuming[a > 0, 
 Integrate[1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r, 
 {z, -a, a}, {r, 0, Infinity}]]

(*  a  *)
```

**EDIT:** Or assume that a is real but not zero.

```
Assuming[a > 0 || a < 0, 
 Integrate[1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -a, a}]]

(*  a  *)

Assuming[a > 0 || a < 0, 
 Integrate[1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r, {z, -a, a}, {r, 0, Infinity}]]

(*  a  *)

Assuming[Element[a, Reals] && a != 0, 
 Integrate[1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -a, a}]]

(*  a  *)

Assuming[Element[a, Reals] && a != 0, 
 Integrate[1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r, {z, -a, a}, {r, 0, Infinity}]]

(*  a  *)
```

Comment: The answer is the same if a is positive or negative, the integral over r actually gives a constant that is independent of z. Even with Assuming[Im[a]==0, Integrate[1/(1 + z^2) Exp[-r^2/(1 + z^2)] r, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -a, a}]] still gives wrong answer.

Comment: Well, its a bug. Assumption a!=0 is not necessary. The correct answer is equal to a in any case.